# using a struct to iterate through coordinates in cmake

Tags: c++

Im working on a grid system in cmake and I want to automate creating the grip using a struct here is an example of what I'm working with

```c
struct Vertex {
    float xyzw[4];
};
```

this struct will be used to hold vertices

```
Vertex verts[] = {}
```

currently, my grid system is built as such

```
Vertex L1 = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
Vertex L2 = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };
```

L1 and L2 will go into my verts as such

```c
verts[] = {L1, L2}
```

and that will create a line. now I am having trouble with thinking of a way to automate this process with a for loop. any advice would be great

Comment: The random `*` bits thrown in the code are really not helping.

Comment: @tadman I think they meant to mark code sections with asterisks

Comment: You can't create an array like that in a `for` loop. Consider: `std::vector` if you're using C++.

Comment: @HenriqueBucher Fixed it for reference.

Comment: I have a feeling "cmake" is a red herring here. This is just C++ code, isn't it?

Comment: Is there anything to do with cmake? I don't see.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using arrays, you could use `int` pointers instead, which are basically arrays. I think you could do something like this:

[Try it on Godbolt!](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIM6SuADJ4DJgAcj4ARpjE/gCspAAOqAqETgwe3r7%2ByanpAiFhkSwxcWaJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BXLaY9o4CdQ0ERRHRsXoK9Y3NOW0jvf0lZRIAlLaoXsTI7BzmAMyhyN5YANQmm25OI8SYrEfYJhoAgls7e5iHx8gj6LR4UVc393deaSM%2B2YbAUSSYa327yOVjuoQI%2BxYTFCEHmJgA7LDbvscft4fsAG6xAgKLgmeJWeIAEReNIxFn2bX2GlIzNZXEO6KpMN%2BuLxgkJxIUZnJlLpmzpmP2AFomSy2YzOdzNljebj4QAqDWCxoKADyXgIPLufKJuoNCKONIgmo180RYloqGQEDSAC9MKgqDbBHb9trJGiVfsAPQh/YASQY6TEeA9%2BwICGeywRKXhsQTqH2acEsQUrIA7oQEPsABw6xxrBRqnH8Yg%2BhF4WnMmF4l5ufaSVt4azWe30mt8iv6w2invU5sNu1I2hOl3uz3e%2BH27VmIMMsOR6OOWPxi7IEuhfAEvDoLxiCuYVSDjHck24zceJIAT32qDNCaTFbwVcHdYbbZWi2wZNkcHZdiBvaWP2mKDqaQoWmO5LchSGjIc2ZokmSFLjsqWJ8ref4kABoESsBDKkeB3ZQRYMH4UOOKYSORo4chorYeKNJMSKrHUsa2K4oRdxEfW%2BKkTSaEge2nbUZYfacvRDFoIa7ZgYcZhmOo6lmKpxzDohvEoRYaETmBanmDp%2BzPiA2m6R2TEGRYuHsehZl6a4tD8QRXK/LeHCLLQnDxLwfgcFopCoJwbg0VCyyrM8Ww8KQBCaP5iwANYgPELKBRwkghalEWcLwCggCyKVhf5pBwLASBXtUhokOQlANMACjKIYHRCAgqAFqFSVoCwSR0EwXQMB1YS0N1vWheFg3DfQcTAFwGmkPNdCxBa019YV9XILcxBtcVgSqNUdT4KFvD8IIIhiOwUgyIIigqOolWkLobQGEYKA0foXylZAiyoEkY2lRwJVxWswwEBdE1dT1O3cLwBDnOsSUFsQTBJJwPABUFBVvZFHDYKdyCNcQ%2ByqKWABs0rU5I%2BzAMgyCMmYAB0OkQNFcmWKyuCECQ6mbFw8zI6l8wZVlOWcPlpCzbwRMlWVyXi3jHBmAT4WKyrlUS6QZppM4khAA%3D%3D)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int verts1[] = { 1, 0, 0, 1 };
    int verts2[] = { -1, 0, 0, 1 };

    int** vertsOut;
    vertsOut = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * 4); // Initialize the out pointer to pointers, with 8 vertices
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        vertsOut[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2); // Initialize each individual vertex
    }
    // Copy over the vertices
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        vertsOut[i][0] = verts1[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        vertsOut[i][1] = verts2[i];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << "x: " << vertsOut[i][0] << "  y: " << vertsOut[i][1] << endl;
    }
}
```